# How to show '->' in front of the directory information in Linux when do ll -a?

Tags: linux, directory

Actually as shown bellow I wondered
How to show '->' in front of the directory information in Linux when do ll -a?
Is it something related to repository/git or it is done by another person intentionally?[image]

Answer (score 1):

The printed line with the `->` is a symbolic link. Not really a directory (or a standard file).
The name of the link is `latest` (size of 5 characters). The target of this link is `9.0.2` (in the same directory).
So it's done intentionally by another person or a install program.
Read `man ln` for futher information. `ln` is the command for create links.
There is no relation with Git or whatelse like it.

Comment: Thanks Arnaud for your answer. One more question is this is the dynamic target link or static.
I mean if we have 2 folder: 9.0.2 and 9.0.3, the latest can be automatically point to 9.0.3? Or I should change it manually?

Comment: It's only static